# Add subtasks to this JQL query

Tags: jira, jql

I managed to create a JQL + ScriptRunner query for my Kanban board that shows all the epics and contained task that the current user would be interested in as follows:

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("assignee = currentUser()", "has Epic") OR 
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf('issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("assignee = currentUser()", "has Epic")', 'is epic of')
```

This works well.

My problem is now - I want it to also display the subtasks of the issues related to the issues displayed.

How do I do it?